# React not sending cookies to Rails backend but Postman does

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, web-development-server

I'm building a web forum app in which users would be granted access to delete post after logging in. It works pretty fine with postman. When I send a post request

```
{
    "username":"admin"
}
```

to http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/login , it returns

```
{
    "logged_in": true,
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "admin",
        "created_at": "2024-01-16T08:20:06.833Z",
        "updated_at": "2024-01-16T08:54:12.423Z"
    }
}
```

and subsequent operations like deleting post and commenting is successful.

However when I tried to do the same thing via react frontend, it does not work.
I first submitted a login form to the same login api, and here are the response headers which includes a Set-Cookie and a status code of 200

```
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/login
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
200 OK
Remote Address:
127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
http://localhost:3001
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:
Access-Control-Max-Age:
7200
Cache-Control:
max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Length:
133
Content-Type:
application/json; charset=utf-8
Etag:
W/"3e40f54fa2dc1627bb4165f169830629"
Referrer-Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Server-Timing:
start_processing.action_controller;dur=0.01, sql.active_record;dur=0.22, instantiation.active_record;dur=0.13, render.active_model_serializers;dur=0.27, process_action.action_controller;dur=6.07
Set-Cookie:
_session_id=N7hExqEzk80WChjp8jyo5LYrU0RIfOtkC9rXNU%2BizgqBqEDxl9ElcSQaLnCcpQQEKAKyWTrPyP8RLPPzmySIOH8ICfq1YDbh16evusVOlXdo1AHTByyvD6dpJEZd08QCBm2blo1T4Zj6MHWCpKiif2T7ENeX%2BSA7Fg7ZO9%2F4sC0IGb8a0bXJJpHvEZorQuaWmFYX--MuwIUcMNjna5dBG6--V8taY0fcFOZSQ%2FuF50g6gw%3D%3D; path=/; httponly; SameSite=Lax
Vary:
Accept, Origin
X-Content-Type-Options:
nosniff
X-Frame-Options:
SAMEORIGIN
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies:
none
X-Request-Id:
8e908f20-30ba-4e83-8470-f0072111de28
X-Runtime:
0.043244
X-Xss-Protection:
0
```

Now when I try to delete posts, it says I'm unauthorised , and Cookie is missing is the headers

```
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/posts/24/comments/28
Request Method:
DELETE
Status Code:
401 Unauthorized
Remote Address:
127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
http://localhost:3001
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:
Access-Control-Max-Age:
7200
Cache-Control:
no-cache
Content-Length:
26
Content-Type:
application/json; charset=utf-8
Referrer-Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Server-Timing:
start_processing.action_controller;dur=0.04, sql.active_record;dur=0.11, instantiation.active_record;dur=0.32, render.active_model_serializers;dur=0.09, halted_callback.action_controller;dur=0.01, process_action.action_controller;dur=5.85
Vary:
Accept, Origin
X-Content-Type-Options:
nosniff
X-Frame-Options:
SAMEORIGIN
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies:
none
X-Request-Id:
981301cd-d533-4ecb-b476-a40614d2d9ca
X-Runtime:
0.116002
X-Xss-Protection:
0
Accept:
*/*
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:
zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection:
keep-alive
Content-Type:
application/json
Dnt:
1
Host:
127.0.0.1:3000
Origin:
http://localhost:3001
Referer:
http://localhost:3001/
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:
cross-site
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

**Thing that I've tried:**

I have added credentials:"include" in my fetch function:

```
const handleDelete = (postId: number) => {
    const deleteURL = `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/posts/${postId}`;

    fetch(deleteURL, {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      credentials: "include",
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          setThreadTrigger((n: number) => n + 1); // Increment threadTrigger to refetch threads
        } else if (response.status === 401) {
          alert(
            "Access Denied: You are not authorized to perform this action. Please login using username 'admin' "
          );
          throw new Error("Unauthorized");
        } else {
          throw new Error("Failed to delete thread");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error deleting thread", error));
  };
```

In my backend cors.rb, I've also added credentials:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'http://localhost:3001'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :patch, :put, :delete],
credentials: true
  end
end
```

and this is my session_store.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_session_id', same_site: :lax
```

I would appreciate if anyone could tell me what's going wrong.